# Scene changing causes Unity MARS Camera to fail for my project

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have some issues occurring in my project and a little guide will be helpful.
In my project there are three Scenes, say 1,2,3, in which Scene 1 consist Simple Mian Camera and Scene 2 and 3 consist MARS Camera. I use Scene 1 as Menu bar for scene changing with two buttons that will lead to either scene 2 or 3 and from that scene a back will bring back to scene 1. I am also using XR Origin for AR Plane Detection and Point Cloud Detection and AR Session.

Now the issue is that, when I go from Scene 1 to scene 2, the Mars Camera works properly but when I go back from Scene 2 to Scene 1 and then try to go to scene 3 or scene 2, the camera shows error. Same thing happens when I go from Scene 1 to scene 3  to again scene 1 and then to either scene 2 or 3.

In the issue,
Scene 2, the Plane and Point Cloud Detection gets stopped and Image Marker does not work either and
Scene 3, the only UI gets displayed and the background becomes black.

I have searched about it but couldn't able to find any answer that would solve my issues or at least give me some ideas.

It will be helpful if you could give me some kind setting ideas, codes, resource links or anything that will solve this issue.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me a lot if multi-scene is something not really supported there ... this is a bit older but basically saying "have only one" ^^ https://forum.unity.com/threads/mars-scene-change.1021252  - I would directly contact Unity support / report a bug

Comment: Yes, I have seen that approach and thought of using it too. But the issue is that, in of the scene I have added a GameObject in the MARS Session. So, it becomes a little difficult to manage it but I will try to do something with that.

But will it be possible if I active the MARS Session on scene Load and switch off in scene unload?

Comment: Tbh I don't know .. you'll have to try